# looking for the text of the mezuzah in the sofer font

Tags: safrus, mezuzah

Where can I find the font of mezuzah in the ktav stam (the way its written in the mezuzah) not in picture, but in text "so I can copy paste the text"?

Comment: https://www.fonts.com/font/masterfont/torah/regular

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why not?

Comment: @DoubleAA How is this any different than, say, the entire [tag:product-recommendation] tag?

Comment: @Avrohom Are you just asking for the text, or do you want the text in the Sofer font? If it's the former, you can find the first paragraph [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.4-9) and the second paragraph [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.13-21). If you want it in the Sofer font, then you won't be able to just copy-paste it; you'll need to have the font installed on your computer, so you might as well get the font and the text, and just format the text to be in that font.

Comment: @Doniel Those are for use in Judaism

Comment: @DoubleAA Is the scope limited to things used within Judaism? Aren't questions about things related to Judaism allowed, even if it's not used within Judaism?

Comment: @DonielF Im not sure as regards product-recommendations

Comment: @donielIF even I cannot copy paste it, as long as it’s computerized.

Answer (score 2):

This link should have the font of the Alef Bet you're looking for, and allows the ability to copy/paste:

https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/